# How to pass props to all pages from getInitialProps in Next.js

Tags: javascript, next.js

I want to get same props in all pages that I load. I try to do it with `_app.js` like this:

```js
export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
    return <Component {...pageProps} />
}
    
MyApp.getInitialProps = async (appContext) => {
    return {
        props: {
            testApp: ['1', '2', '3'],
            testApp2: '222'
        }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work. I get an empty object:

```js
const Error = (props) => {
    console.log(props);

    return (
        <div className="error-page">
            ...
        </div>
    )
}
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The structure of the return object in `getInitialProps` is slightly different than `getServerSideProps` or `getStaticProps` - you don't need the extra `props` nesting, you simply return the object with the props.

```js
MyApp.getInitialProps = async (appContext) => {
    return {
        testApp: ['1', '2', '3'],
        testApp2: '222'
    }
}
```

Comment: Didn't works for me