# nextjs getInitialProps() not passing props to class components

Tags: reactjs, next.js

im getting empty results. what im i doing wrong?

indx.js:

```
export default class Home extends React.Component {

  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {

    const test = 'test 123'

    return {props: {test: test}}
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.props.test)
    return (
      <>
        <h1>{this.props.test}</h1>
      </>
    )
  }
}
```

_app.js:

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
 return (
    <Component {...pageProps} />
  )
}

export default MyApp
```

getting undeifend on the 'console.log' and the 'h1' is emtpy

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass props to all pages from getInitialProps in Next.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65988842/how-to-pass-props-to-all-pages-from-getinitialprops-in-next-js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should `return` the component's props without putting it in another `props` object. [`Read the Docs`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/getInitialProps)

```
static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
  const test = 'test 123';
  return { test };
}
```